# How to convert SPL2SMAP_S data (available in .h5 files) to *.tiff files?

Tags: raster, gdal, georeferencing, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I had downloaded some data from https://nsidc.org/data/SPL2SMAP_S
The description of the data is given in the page.
Using an earthdata login, one can download the data.
The data consists of `*.xml` and `*.h5` files.[image]

Before downloading the data i selected the region as is seen in the picture above.

I tried

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF5:"SMAP_L2_SM_SP_1AIWDV_20200103T012207_20200103T010733_073E32N_R16515_001.h5"://Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_3km/water_body_fraction_3km out.tiff
```

This output tiff when projected in QGIS was off
[image]
I am looking for `water_body_fraction_3km` actually.
I need help in creating a georeferenced tiff file (raster) containing this value.

Answer (score 2):

- Step 1: Go to https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search?q=SPL2SMAP_S
- Step 2: Select the tile that pops up
- Step 3: Filter granules by date and region
- Step 4: Select `+ Add to Project` on right
- Step 5: Select `My Project` button that appears
- Step 6: Select `More Options`
- Step 7: Select `Customize` under `Select Data Access Method`
- Step 8: Under `Reformat Output` select `GeoTiff` for output file format & select `Done`
- Step 9: Select `Download Data` button